# How to look at different parameters from an object from within the same method?

Tags: java, oop

I have a Contact class which has name, email and address. I store them inside an `ArrayList`. Right now I have three different methods that are used for letting the user search a contact by name, email or address. Each one does exactly the same as the others except for the comparison statement, one has `name.equals(contact.getName())`, another `email.equals(contact.getEmail())` and the last one has `address.equals(contact.getAddress())`. I am aware of the DRY principle and I think it can be applied here, is there a way to avoid repeating myself in this case?

```
public void searchName(String name)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++)
    {
      Contact contact = contacts.get(i);

      if(name.equals(contact.getName())
       {
          printContactInfo(contact);
       }
     }
}
```

The other two methods are exactly the same but instead of using name they use email or address.

Answer (score 2):

You could pass this as a Function. Java 8's syntax enhancements lend themselves nicely to such usecases:

```
public void searchName(String name) {
    search(name, Contact::getName);
}

public void searchEmail(String email) {
    search(email, Contact::getEmail);
}

public void searchAddress(String address) {
    search(address, Contact::getAddress);
}

private void search(String s, Function<Contact, String> f) {
    contacts.stream().filter(c -> f.apply(c).equals(s)).forEach(this::printContactInfo);
}
```

Comment: It looks like OP searches for all matches to print them - not only for the first one. There is no `break` in the for loop.

Comment: @LuCio Nice catch, thanks. I'm seeing things :-) Edited and fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Mureinik looks good, but could you explain the search function? I'm not familiar with what you did there.

Answer (score 1):

Define your three search methods which all delegate to a "master" search method.  Implementing the enum needed for this and the actual logic behind the search is an exercise left for the reader.

```
public void searchName(String name) {
    search(SearchType.NAME, name);
}

public void searchEmail(String email) {
    search(SearchType.EMAIL, email);
}

public void searchAddress(String address) {
    search(SearchType.ADDRESS, address);
}

private void search(SearchType type, String value) {
    switch(type) {
        case NAME:
        break;
        case EMAIL:
        break;
        case ADDRESS:
        break;
    }
}
```